# Memory leak when variables go out of scope but variables are actually needed out of scope

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

This code causes a memory leak because of the vector inside the for a loop. I am currently aware that this can be avoided by not using pointers in C++. However, I need to use pointers in my code. This is an equivalent (proof of concept) of my actual code in C in which I have no other option, but to use pointers. I used C++ for my question because it makes it shorter and easier to visualize. In my actual code, I use a `TreeMap` instead of a `vector` and a `HashMap` instead of a `queue` from the `Libgee` library. I don't write my actual code because to make sense of it, I would have to post over a thousand lines of code and that makes it unfeasible for my question. This is a minified equivalent that programmatically causes the same problem of memory leak and has the same logic. In the end, I will use the queue (HashMap in my code) until the user decides to run the loop again to get new values. The reason for which I cannot declare `containerVector` outside of the loop is that each `containerVector` needs to be different for each iteration of i.

TL;DR Variables that are created inside a for loop will be needed outside the loop, but references get lost and cause memory leaks. Variables **need** to be pointers.

Is there a way to avoid a memory leak here while still using pointers? I don't know beforehand how many vectors (which here stand for a TreeMap in my C code) I will need and they must be created as a pointer inside the for a loop.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    queue< vector<int>* >* containerQueue = new queue< vector<int>* >;

    // Unknown for loop size before running program
    for (int i = 0; i < rand() % 1000 + 10000; i++) {
        vector<int>* containerVector = new vector<int>;
        // Unknown nested loop size before running the program
        for (int j = 0; j < rand() % 100 + 50; j++) {
            // If a condition is met
            if (j % 2) {
                    // Add a value to the vector
                    containerVector->push_back(j);
            }
        }
        // Release memory pointed by containerVector if it was not used
        if (containerVector->empty()) delete containerVector;
        // Add the vector to the queue
        containerQueue->push(containerVector);
        // If containerVector were to be freed here, the memory leak issue is solved,
        // But containerQueue would then become useless
    }
    // Use containerQueue here
    // The values of containerVector are needed in this part of the code

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just delete the vectors after you are done with them?

Comment: But how? Their references are no longer available outside the for loop.

Comment: You just saved them all in a queue... Anyhow, it is absolutely unclear why you need pointers, even if you must, there is `std::unique_ptr` or its worse version, manual deletion

Comment: Not sure if it's just because the code isn't 1:1 with the C version, but you should probably wrap the `queue->push(vector)` part in an `else` so you don't add a freed pointer to the queue.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for pointing it out user9549915. Also, deleting the vectors from the queue worked, Frank and Passer By. Thanks all.

Comment: Passer By, I need to use pointers because Libgee is in C and the TreeMap and HashMap from it can only be used by declaring them as pointers. In C++ this would be unnecessary, but I asked the question in C++ because the equivalent code that follows the same logic is shorter this way for me to ask the question. Anyways, thanks for the tip, it worked.

Comment: @g_ in C++ you can wrap raw pointers in smart pointers, even C provided pointers.